# Table - Different column width

Tags: html, html-table

Any help would be much appreciated with the coding on a table of info. The table works great in Chrome and Firefox but NOT in IE8. I have tried various but with no luck. The person who I am doing it wants it as in Chrome/Firefox look, nothing else.

The two rows up from the bottom have different width than the columns above. As in chrome / Firefox. Just need it get it to show the same in IE8. IE8 displays them all in the same width?!

```
  <table width="669" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="56" rowspan="18" bgcolor="#E6E6E6" >
         <p align="center">
             <img src="images/awards.gif" alt="Awards" width="22" height="109" align="absmiddle" /></p></td>
                    <td width="66" height="44" ><strong>Category</strong></td>
                    <td  ><div align="center">Awards</div></td>
                    <td colspan="2"><div align="center">Value</div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td width="66" rowspan="4" valign="top"><div align="right"><strong>MAIN</strong></div></td>
                    <td width="154" >1st prize and the title <br />
                      of the Young Pianist<br />
                    of the North</td>
                    <td colspan="2" valign="top" class="style3" >&pound;600.00</td>
                </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td width="154" >2nd prize</td>
                    <td colspan="2" class="style3">&pound;400.00</td>
                </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td width="154" >3rd prize</td>
                    <td colspan="2" valign="top"><span class="style3">&pound;200.00</span> in total value<br />
                    (<span class="style3">&pound;100.00</span> and WUe* worth <span class="style3">&pound;100.00</span> or more)</td>
                </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td width="154" height="26" >Up to 3 Diplomas</td>
                    <td colspan="2" ><div align="center">-</div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td height="16" colspan="4" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
```

The link with HTML table code is [here](http://kl1p.com/TJnb)

Comment: Nice workaround for the jsfiddle only check. Seriously, you show identify the relevant parts of the codes and put it in your question so that it can stand on its own without linking to external resources.

Comment: First run your code through a [html validator](http://validator.w3.org/), fixing any errors/warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Post your full code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), your question was unclear.

what i can read from your question is, you have alignment issues in width of row? If so try adding this compatible meta header for Internet explorer

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
```

Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge)